# One to many relationship not working in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using FluentHibernate and Automapping. My classes are

```
public class Student
{
  public Student()
  {
    Books = new List<Book>(); 
  }
  public virtual int Id{get;private set;}
  public virtual string Name{get;set;}
  public virtual IList<Book> Books { get; private set; }
}

public class Book
{
  public  Book (){} 
  public virtual int Id{get;private set;}
  public virtual string Name{get;set;}
}

Now, I create book objects and to a student object, and call save.
Book b = new Book();
b.Name = "test"
Book b1 = new Book();
b2.Name = "test1" 

Student student = new Student();
student.Books.Add(b);
student.Books.Add(b1);
session.saveorupdate(student);
```

Only student is saved not the books. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Cascade.SaveUpdate()` to your automapping file. It should look something like:

```
HasMany(x => x.Books).Cascade.All();
```

Comment: yes, you are correct. That's what I ended-up doing eventually.

Comment: I added this, and no update is ran. It only inserts the children with no reference, and never updates.

Comment: Please create a new question, it'll be easier to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is the many to many relationship not one to many (to assign more students to one unique book item and vice versa).
So you need to add `public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }` to Book class as well.
Also call save method after adding each book to populate its Id automatically from database.